# Как создать спецификацию для сваггера из кастомного объекта?

Tags: c#, openapi

У меня есть следующий класс:

```
[ApiEndpoint( Name, SignatureBase )]
[Title]
[Description]
abstract public class ReportsAPI
{
    public const string Name = "reports";

    public const string SignatureBase = "/system/report";

    static public readonly EndpointSignature Signature =
        SignatureBase;

    public class TitleAttribute
        : TitleLocalizedAttribute
    {
        public TitleAttribute()
            : base(typeof(Resources.ReportsAPITitle))
        {
        }
    }

    public class DescriptionAttribute
        : DescriptionLocalizedAttribute
    {
        public DescriptionAttribute()
            : base(typeof(Resources.ReportsAPIDescription))
        {
        }
    }

    [ApiCommands]
    abstract public class Commands
    {
        [ApiArgument(typeof(ReportTemplatesListArguments), isOptional: true)]
        [ApiReturn(typeof(ReportTemplatesListResponse))]
        [Title]
        [Description]
        public const string ReportTemplatesList = "report_templates_list";

        [ApiArgument(typeof(ReportTemplatesGetArguments))]
        [ApiReturn(typeof(ReportTemplatesGetResponse))]
        [Title]
        [Description]
        public const string ReportTemplatesGet = "report_templates_get";

        [ApiArgument(typeof(ReportsGenerateArguments))]
        [ApiReturn(typeof(ReportsGenerateResponse))]
        [Title]
        [Description]
        public const string ReportsGenerate = "reports_generate";
    }

    [ApiEvents]
    abstract public class Events
    {
        [ApiReturn(typeof(ReportGenerateStartedEvent))]
        [Title]
        [Description]
        [EventCategory(EventCategoryType.Audit)]
        [EventIsVerbalized]
        public const string ReportGenerateStarted = "report_generate_started";
    }
}
```

атрибут `ApiCommands` говорит о том, что перед нами команды, которые можно вызвать, `ApiArgument` - аргументы, `ApiReturn` - то, что возвращается
вот хотелось бы все это в виде `openapi` спецификации описать

Comment: Из кастомного объекта не знаю, но для генерации Open API спецификации используют NuGet пакет Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.